# Passing variable to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to render a partial for each offer.
I have the following code:

offers/index.html.haml:

```
- @offers.each do |o|
  = render 'offershort', locals: {offer: o}
```

offers/_offershort.html.haml:

```
= link_to offer.name, offer_path
= offer.description
```

I get an error:

> undefined local variable or method `offer'

How to do it properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the short version, you need to drop the `locals` option

```
= render 'offershort', offer: o
```

otherwise

```
= render partial: 'offershort', locals: { offer: o }
```

Comment: @SimoneCarletti how come its different for the short version?

Comment: This issue dogged me for a l o n g time. Who knew there was a difference between render and render partial:  ???